# Confirming the validity of a point process model

Tags: spatial, point-process, spatstat

I have a question regarding a point process model I generated for a biological point pattern exhibiting repulsion and attraction at different scales. My goal for this model was to generate simulated point patterns that I could then use for between group hypothesis testing, with simulated patterns from other groups.

I've fit a hierarchical Geyer point process model to the data to attempt to capture these interactions, but I was unsure if I was correctly interpreting the model fit and was hoping to get insight onto whether the model reasonably fits the data for my purpose. I'm still new to point pattern analysis, so the confirmation is really helpful. I've attached several diagnostic plots below for reference - it appears the summed raw residuals are near zero [-.1512], the range of the relative fitted intensity to actual intensity is near 1 [0.509, 1.17] and the the qqplot, Gres, and Kres plots are within the 95% confidence band for 100 simulations [see below]. The only thing I was worried about was the G residual function having some deviation very close to the 95% band at r range between ~2-3um, and some deviation in the K residual plot at large r distances, though it is still within the confidence band. I've tried to correct for this with changing parameters and trialing different hybrid models but have had little success. Am I interpreting properly that this model fits the data reasonably well?

[image: smoothed residual plot]
[image: qq plot]
[image: K residual plot]
[image: G residual plot]